# Creating a SSL socket connection

Tags: javascript, ssl, websocket, connection

I need to connect to a remote server on a specific socket.
I have no control over the remote server, but I need to connect, send commands and retrieve the results.

I'm looking to do this in a browser extension so thought about using javascript or websockets, but would be happy to be guided on this.

As an example the remote server is on `x.x.x.x port 1234`

In bash I can connect and interact using: `openssl s_client -connect x.x.x.x:1234`

In php I use the following:

```
$param = array(
  'ssl' => array(
      'verify_peer' => false,
      'verify_peer_name' => false,
      )
  );

$context = stream_context_create($param);
$socket = stream_socket_client (
  "x.x.x.x:1234", $errno, $errstr, $timeout,
  STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context)
```

I've tried using the following and it fails due to the server cert being self signed.

```
ws.connect('wss://x.x.x.x:1234');
ws.onopen = function()
{
alert ("Connected");
};
```

I have no control over the server / certificate, so I need to try and work with that. The openssl and php commands both work. fine

Anyone any ideas or suggestions on how I can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: The self-signed certificate has to be trusted by the browser, i.e. the user has to explicitly import it as trusted. Apart from that WebSockets as you do in the JavaScript and Sockets as you do in PHP are not the same, i.e. WebSockets require the server to implement the WebSockets protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Is there no way to do this ? I have no control over the remote server so can't get a cert that is trusted.